# Replace cell value in pandas dataframe where value is 'NaN' with value from another/same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The following pandas dataframe df1 was generated:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Value': [1.989920, 'NaN', -9.363819, 'NaN'], 'Group-Index' : [6, 6, 7, 7], 'Group-Order' : [2, 2, 2, 2], 'Index' : [221, 225, 222, 222] })

            Value       Group-Index Group-Order     Index
221         1.989920    6           2               221
225         NaN         6           2               225
222         -9.363819   7           2               222
278         NaN         7           2               222
```

beware that the pandas index varies because I've used the dataframe output from my actual project.

and there is a second dataframe df2 available which looks as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1.989920, -9.363819], 'Group-Index' : [6, 7], 'Group-Order' : [2, 2], 'Index' : [221, 222] })

        Value       Group-Index     Group-Order     Index
221     1.989920    6               2               221
222     -9.363819   7               2               222
```

1. How can I search through the GC-Value column in the first dataframe and find all NaN values and then replace them with the value from the second dataframe where the Group-Index and the Group-Order column are the same in both rows of both dataframes?
2. Another solution to my problem would be to copy the value from the row where a value is defined to the NaN-cell matching with the Group-Index and Group-Order within the same dataframe df1.

Thus, the result should be:

```
            Value       Group-Index Group-Order     Index
221         1.989920    6           2               221
225         1.989920    6           2               225
222         -9.363819   7           2               222
278         -9.363819   7           2               222
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vnull = df1.Value.isnull()
mrg_cols = ['Group-Index', 'Group-Order']
df1.loc[vnull, 'Value'] = df2.merge(df1.loc[vnull, mrg_cols]).Value.values

df1
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this solution doesn't work. There is no error output and the first dataframe df1 remains unchanged. I have added two lines to easily generate the dataframes I'm referencing.